# Expression ssis filter date

Tags: ssis

How can I write an expression with ssis in conditional filter in order to do  filter on date

date should between june to auguest 2014 and june till august 2015 ?

I try

```
(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==6 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2015 )||(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==7 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2015 )||(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==8 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2015 )||(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==6 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2014 )||(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==7 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2014 )||(DATEPART(“MONTH”,[Date Time])==8 && DATEPART(“Year”,[Date Time])==2014 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

`MONTH([Date Time])>=6&&MONTH([Date Time])<=8&&YEAR([Date Time])>=2014&&YEAR([Date Time])<=2015`

is a bit tidier and should be accurate.

It's more efficient to treat the dates as number ranges when you don't need to account for different month lengths, holidays, etc.